# RegEx white space between elements

Tags: c#, regex

I am saving the html page as text where I want to pull out names from the file using RegEx. Nothing is being returned, I think because of the white space between the element. I tried to add `\s*` between the span and anchor. PLEASE HELP me fix it...

Here is an example of the html:

```
<li>
     <span class="name">
           <a href="/players/player-name.html">Stanley,&nbsp;Kyle</a>
     </span>
</li>
```

I am using C#, here is my code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"textfile.txt"))
        {

            string content = r.ReadToEnd();

            Regex r1 = new Regex("<span class=\"name\"><a.*>(.*?)</a></span>");

            MatchCollection mc = r1.Matches(content);
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

Comment: So you tried to add `\s*`. Can you show us an example of how you did that? Also, don’t parse HTML with regular expressions. Use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or something.

Comment: Note that if you weren’t using a verbatim string or a double-backslash, it’ll just end up the same as `s`. So `@"<span class=""name"">\s*<a.*>(.*?)</a>\s*</span>"`, and mind the `@`.

Comment: Thank you, I added:
@"<span class=""name"">\s*<a.*>(.*?)</a>\s*</span>" - AND it worked!!! Perfection!!!

Comment: @user3371361 You would be better off using a proper html parser instead of regex. Also, you are supposed to mark the answer that solved your problem, not when it didn't...

Comment: I don't now how to "accept" a comment as an answer?!

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex r1 = new Regex(
  @"<span class=""name"">\s*<a.*?>(.*?)</a>\s*</span>",
  RegexOptions.Multiline
);
```

Comment: I get a compile error "Unrecognized escape sequence" highlighting the s in the regex.

Comment: Here is the one with the escape sequence...  Regex r1 = new Regex("<span class=\"name\">\\s*<a.*?>(.*?)</a>\\s*</span>",  RegexOptions.Multiline);